# Add new element to DOM on action in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, html-rendering

What would be a proper way to dynamically add a new element to DOM in Ember? For example a tooltip. Currently I render all tooltips right away, but they're hidden and only shown on mouse over, which takes time to render anyways. I could use jquery or plain JS to append element on event and it would probably work, but would it be the most efficient way to do so? Also would be nice to still be able to use a template, so code wouldn't be too large.

Comment: Use `#if` and `#else` helpers to render the tooltip based on sort of state?

Comment: If I understand glimmer correctly, it'll still create opcodes for my tooltips content, which essentially means rendering. What I'd like to do is to avoid even touching that part of template until I really need to show it.

Comment: I'm not much of an ember person myself, but more of a React person. The same principle applies though right? Instead of modifying the DOM directly or using jQuery, just manage it through the model, then have the model affect the view accordingly. That follows the basic principles of encapsulation and it prevents wonky stuff from happening.

Comment: That's correct... In ideal world :( I have a huge table with components and other dynamic stuff that takes 700ms to render, so I want to make it almost static and render something only if it's really necessary. Though I need to check, maybe `#if` helps

Answer (score 1):

Directly manipulating the DOM is very much a no-no in an Ember app. You want to make it an Ember component of course!

In any page, route, or component template:

```
{{#if showTooltip}}    
  {{tooltip text=someMessage}}
{{/if}}
```

and then in, say, /pods/components/tooltip/component.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  text: 'hello there! this is a tooltip'
})
```

and finally a template for the component /pods/component/tooltip/template.hbs

```
<span class='tooltip-text'>{{text}}</span>
```

In your controlling context, say a component or a controller, you might have a handler like this then:

```
onMouseOver (event) {
  this.set('showTooltip', true)
},

onMouseOut (event) {
  this.set('showTooltip', false)
}
```

And these handlers could be actions or just native events on a component, triggered based on whatever DOM interaction event you want.

This will give you a template based tool-tip that only renders in the controlling context if you've set the `showTooltip` property to `true`.  It's as close to what you are asking for as you are going to get in an Ember app.

Comment: I used similar approach with popovers with use of service and shared popover container component, that was rendering supplied component by name with arguments. It partially solves the issue, but... I'm not really satisfied with initial rendering in Ember, so I tried to cut it to bare minimum so rendered content was pretty much static, until some action happened.

Comment: I really do think that is the way to do that, in Ember, at least.  It will not put that stuff in the DOM, at all, until the user initiates an action that triggers the re-render with the tooltip.  Such is the Ember way.

Comment: If I understand it right, glimmer converts whole template into AST, and in that AST it'll have to unwrap tooltip call and convert it into opcodes as well, cause it doesn't know whether it will be called or not. Though I'm not sure if actual rendering is what costs the most, or this compiling stage.

Comment: @IvanYouroff That part is _highly_ optimized and costs next to nothing. The expensive part that can impact user experience and page performance is the actual reflow caused by an update to the DOM.  You are safe with the standard Ember approach.

Comment: Well, I'm already observing dramatically slow initial rendering :( But I agree, this probably will be the best solution right now.